# Detect multiple conditions

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm trying to create a simple wine web app with Sinatra. The keys within my Wine model are  "vintner", "vintage", and "varietal". Vintage is an integer. I also have a Note model for users to add in notes (currently separating by commas, will plan to get more robust later...).

Here is my POST action within my WineController:

```
post '/wines' do
  if params[:wine] == ""
    erb :'wines/new'
  else
    @wine = current_user.wines.new(params[:wine])
    @wines = current_user.wines

    if @wines.detect{ |wine| wine.vintner.downcase == 
      @wine.vintner.downcase && wine.varietal.downcase == 
      @wine.varietal.downcase && wine.vintage == @wine.vintage }
      flash[:message] = "That wine is already in your cellar! Add another."
      erb :'/wines/new'
    elsif !params[:note][:name].empty?
      params[:note][:name].split(", ").each{ |user_note| @wine.notes << 
        Note.find_or_create_by(:name => user_note) }
    end
  end

  @wine.save
  redirect to "/wines"
end
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to say "if there is already a wine with that vintner, varietal, and vintage, don't create it and redirect back to the 'new' view with said message. Otherwise, add the notes to the that wine instance, save, and redirect to '/wines/index'".

Instead, though, the wine saves (the notes are not being saved, though) and I get redirected to '/wines/index' with said message. So, that's weird.

My main question is, how can I detect (using detect or any other method) based on three or more criteria. Also, if anyone has any insight into what I'm doing wrong with my notes, I'd love to hear! Thank you!!

Comment: This could be an order-of-operations problem. Try doing `(wine.vintner.downcase == 
    @wine.vintner.downcase) && (wine.varietal.downcase == 
    @wine.varietal.downcase) && (wine.vintage == @wine.vintage)`.

Comment: Are you using Active Record?

Comment: Never used Sinatra, but does calling `erb :'/wines/new'` actually return from the method? looks like you call that and the continue on to `@wine.save` and `redirect` all the way at the bottom of the method outside all conditionals

Comment: @SimpleLime you are correct! Thanks for catching that!!

Comment: @moveson thanks, that would seem logical but it doesn't seem to have an effect. Thank you, though!

Comment: @SaraTibbetts Yes, I am.

Comment: Check out `find_or_create_by` https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it currently is written the lines

```
@wine.save
redirect to "/wines"
```

are outside all the conditionals at the very bottom of the block, so that code will run, even if the condition `params[:wine] == ""` is met, and in that case it will error out because `@wine` doesn't get set.

Try moving that code into maybe the `elsif !params[:note][:name].empty?` branch and then it should only run when you need to create a new wine.